# Website performance certification

Tags: performance, audit

My client is looking for performance audit, something similar to yearly security audit.

Are there any reputed services or vendors that measure and analyze a given website performance and more importantly certify the performance data.

My client's intent is to share such data with future customers.

Comment: Nothing super-fancy, but if you have Google Chrome, fire it up and inspect the loading times and resource usage. It's dead-simple and looks awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a waterfall graph to show the performance. I have used [webpagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org) and am pretty happy with it. It is is also creditable because a lot of big companies use it.

Here is a sample run for SO: http://www.webpagetest.org/result/111031_H2_21NJR/1/details/

So for example time to first byte was 200 ms. This means that browser doesn't start rendering anything until after 200ms. Keeping it < 800ms is generally a good idea.

If you are looking at companies that do this performance test, I would be cautious because they will all say yes and just go to a similar website and say here is your performance analysis.